# how to put arrays into an array pseudocode

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

PROBLEM BACKGROUND: I want to make a code that for HERD_SIZE number of cows, which inputs each cows "identity tag" and then records the milk yield (milked twice a day for a week).

I want to store each days yield in a different array, hence "Yield1 Yield2 etc."

Currently I made an array to store the arrays for each day so that I can index the array containing the day array and then store inputs into that array. Apologies for poor wording.

This is my code:

```
Cows[1:HERD_SIZE]

Yield1[1:(HERD_SIZE*2)] 

Yield2[1:(HERD_SIZE*2)]

Yield3[1:(HERD_SIZE*2)]

Yield4[1:(HERD_SIZE*2)]

Yield5[1:(HERD_SIZE*2)]

Yield6[1:(HERD_SIZE*2)]

Yield7[1:(HERD_SIZE*2)]

**Yields[Yield1,Yield2,Yield3,Yield4,Yield5,Yield6,Yield7]**

FOR Count ← 1 TO HERD_SIZE
    OUTPUT “Please input the identity for Cow”,Count
    INPUT Cow_Identity
    Cows[Count] ← Cow_Identity

    FOR Day ← 1 To 7

        OUTPUT ”Please input the first yield for cow”,Cow_Identity,”on day”, Day
        INPUT First_Yield

        OUTPUT ”Please input the second yield for cow”,Cow_Identity,”on day”, Day
        INPUT Second_Yield

        **(Yields[Day])[Count*2-1] ← First_Yield
        (Yields[Day])[Count*2] ← Second_Yield**
```

Will the method of indexing the Yields array to get (for example) the Yield1 array in which i can store data in work?

Answer (score 0):

How arrays are defined and indexed will very depending on language; but since you are using brackets for array indexes, I will go with what is somewhat common for that.

```
Cows[1:HERD_SIZE]
Yields[1:HERD_SIZE][1:7][1:2]

FOR each Count
    Get_identity
    Cows[Count] ← Cow_Identity
    FOR each Day
        FOR each Milking
            Get_yield_for_milking
            Yields[Count][Day][Milking] ← Yield
```

The use of `Count*2` and `Count*2-1` would be unusual, to say the least.